# Google Query Language: How to average multiple columns when each one has a different condition?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-visualization, google-query-language

## The data

I have a table as the following in Google Sheets:

| Month | Country | Metric Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nov | AAA | Metric_1 | 98 |
| Nov | AAA | Metric_2 | 45 |
| Nov | AAA | Metric_3 | 4 |
| Nov | BBB | Metric_1 | 100 |
| Nov | BBB | Metric_2 | 214 |
| Nov | BBB | Metric_3 | 13 |
| Nov | CCC | Metric_1 | 75 |
| Nov | CCC | Metric_2 | 84 |
| Nov | CCC | Metric_3 | 21 |
| Nov | Worldwide | Metric_4 | 3 |
| Nov | Worldwide | Metric_5 | 87 |
| Oct | AAA | Metric_1 | 94 |
| Oct | AAA | Metric_2 | 41 |
| Oct | AAA | Metric_3 | 0 |
| Oct | BBB | Metric_1 | 96 |
| Oct | BBB | Metric_2 | 210 |
| Oct | BBB | Metric_3 | 9 |
| Oct | CCC | Metric_1 | 71 |
| Oct | CCC | Metric_2 | 82 |
| Oct | CCC | Metric_3 | 17 |
| Oct | Worldwide | Metric_4 | -1 |
| Oct | Worldwide | Metric_5 | 83 |

## Objective

The end goal is to have a table summarizing each metric per month, ideally just the averages:

| Month | Metric_1 | Metric_2 | Metric_3 | Metric_4 | Metric_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nov | 91 | 114.33 | 12.66 | 3 | 87 |
| Oct | 87 | 109.33 | 8.66 | -1 | 83 |

## Failed attempts

My first attempt was using a multitude of `VLOOKUP` functions, but the formulas were only getting messier so I dropped that approach.

I discovered the `QUERY` function and 'Google Visualization API Query Language'. This code works when considering only one metric:

```
+QUERY(my_table,"
  SELECT Col1, AVG(Col4)
  WHERE Col3 = 'Metric_1'
  GROUP BY Col1
  LABEL AVG(Col4) 'Metric_1'
",1)
```

| Month | Metric_1 |
| --- | --- |
| Nov | 91 |
| Oct | 87 |

However, I cannot seem to find how to apply different conditions per column. I was wondering if it's possible to integrate a function like `+IF()` or `+AVERAGEIF()` in the `SELECT` part of the query. Something like:

```
+QUERY(my_table,"
  SELECT Col1,
         AVERAGEIF(Col3,'=Metric_1',Col4),
         AVERAGEIF(Col3,'=Metric_2',Col4),
         AVERAGEIF(Col3,'=Metric_3',Col4),
         AVERAGEIF(Col3,'=Metric_4',Col4),
         AVERAGEIF(Col3,'=Metric_5',Col4),
  GROUP BY Col1
",1)
```

How can the summary table be obtained in a **single** query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({A:D};
 "select Col1,avg(Col4)
  where Col3 is not null
  group by Col1
  pivot Col3")
```

[image]

Comment: I was not familiar with the `PIVOT` clause. It works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: @MartianArts here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses